# postgres flag transform_null_equals=on is failing in JDBC specific situation

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, null, where-clause

I am directly using postgres JDBC driver

The url is working for one SQL and not another SQL though

```
    String url = "jdbc:log4jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/staging_incomingdb?user=" +
            username + "&password=" + password +"&options=-c transform_null_equals=on";
```

NOTE that transform_null_equals turns all c.col = null into c.col is null

I then run this which works..

```
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from CUSTOMER_ORIGINAL_ADDRESS\n" +
                "customeror0_ left outer join CUSTOMER_PRACTICE practices1_ on customeror0_.id=practices1_.address_id\n" +
                "where customeror0_.onBehalfOfClientId=? and customeror0_.addr1=? and customeror0_.addr2=NULL");

        st.setString(1, "dean");
        st.setString(2, "200 Patewood Dr");
```

I then run this which does not work

```
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from CUSTOMER_ORIGINAL_ADDRESS\n" +
                "customeror0_ left outer join CUSTOMER_PRACTICE practices1_ on customeror0_.id=practices1_.address_id\n" +
                "where customeror0_.onBehalfOfClientId=? and customeror0_.addr1=? and customeror0_.addr2=?");

        st.setString(1, "dean");
        st.setString(2, "200 Patewood Dr");
        st.setString(3, null);
```

So when I set the param to null, it is not converted.  Is there any way to fix this?  Basically, this second query returns 0 results when it should return results.  The first query returns results as it should due to the setting.

**I suspect it has something to do with sending the query to postgres JUST before it sends the parameters to postgres**. If I am right, this begs the question, is there a setting to have postgres NOT compile my query until all the params are received since we always send the params along with the query?

Comment: What do you mean but *does not work*? Are you getting an error? Wrong results?

Comment: @GMB edited adding the 'does not work piece' about returning 0 results(bad) and the other returns results.  Anyways, the answers below are correct already.  Just adding this for your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your expectation what `transform_null_equals` does is wrong.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-COMPATIBLE-CLIENTS)

> Note that this option only affects the **exact form** `= NULL`, not other comparison operators or other expressions that are computationally equivalent to some expression involving the equals operator.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

In other words: it will not treat *expressions* that yield null in this way, only if the **keyword** `NULL` is explicitly used in the SQL string.

I guess a parameter for a prepared statement is considered an expression in this case as well.

The same thing happens when you use bind variables in PL/pgSQL:

```
execute 'select count(*) from some_table where some_column = $1' 
    into variable_one
    using some_parameter;
```

The above query will not return anything if `some_parameter` is NULL, even with `transform_null_equals` turned on and `some_column` contains null values.

Comment: So what is the solution here? I'm using a library that automatically builds the query and it builds the query that way using the '=' operator since it does not know what the value will be at runtime. This truly sucks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that, as you mentionned, `transform_null_equals` does not do work with prepared statement.

Fortunately, Postgres supports `null`-safe equality, with standard operator `is [not] distinct from`. I would recommend replacing this:

```
and customeror0_.addr2 = ?
```

With:

```
and customeror0_.addr2 is not distinct from ?
```